# why does clang can't using in this way

Tags: clang, llvm

```
//a.c 
int main() {
 printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

//currently in the llvm-project directory

```
clang -Xclang -load  -Xclang build/lib/LLVMHello.so a.c
```

the command above doesn't take any effect.  while the following commond take effect

```
clang -emit-llvm -c a.c
opt -load build/lib/LLVMHello.so -hello < a.bc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the **LLVMHello demo** register the pass by

```
static RegisterPass<Hello> X("hello", "Hello World Pass");
```

As it is only effective for OPT.

If you want to load it to clang, you can replace the `RegisterPass` with

```
static void registerHelloPass(const PassManagerBuilder &, legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) {
    PM.add(new Hello());
}
static RegisterStandardPasses RegisterMyPass(PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible, registerHelloPass);
```

Then you could use `clang -Xclang -load -Xclang XXX.so`. In this way, you would load it either in clang or in opt.